# Search and replace a special character in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to search a character and replace it with a string. First, I search for ':' and replace it with 'to'. Next I want to search '$' and replace it with 'END'. This is the code that I've tried. In below code, it work for the first character but not the second character. I tried to use backslash to escape the special character '$' but it still did not work. What else can I do?

```
$string = "[9:8],
if ($string =~ /^.*:+/){
   $stringreplaced =~ s/:/to/g;
}

elsif ($string =~ /^.*\$+/){
   $stringreplaced =~ s/\$/END/g;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `if/elseif` just do `$string =~ s/\$/END/g;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code you posted doesn't even compile, yet you say it actually ran. Only post code that you've run.

Second, you're matching against the wrong string. You're checking if `$string` contains the character, but you replace the characters in `$stringreplaced`. ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. This would have caught this error.

Third, you only check if the character (`:` or `$`) is on the first line. This is because `.` doesn't match line feeds without `/s`.

Finally, You only check if the string contains `$` if it doesn't contain `:` because you used `elsif`.

The following is all you need:

```perl
$string =~ s/:/to/g;
$string =~ s/\$/END/g;
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the incomplete code. This question only involves a part of my work thus posting everything here might not be a good idea. Your answer is very helpful as I now know that my search pattern is correct.